# Troubleshooting 'Not Found' Error in Power Automate Flow for Updating and Deleting Google Calendar Events from Outlook Trigger

Tags: office365, power-automate

**Description:**

I am attempting to set up a Power Automate flow that integrates the Outlook: When an event is added, updated or deleted (V3) trigger with Google Calendar's create, update, and delete actions.

**Issue:**

I have encountered a problem with the update and delete actions in Google Calendar. Specifically, I am receiving a "Not Found" error when trying to execute these actions. However, the create action works without any issues.

**Error Message:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "Not Found"
      }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

**My flow:**

[image]

**Questions:**

I am wondering if I might be using the wrong ID for the events. Is it necessary to query the event in some way before attempting to update or delete it? I have been unable to find any helpful information that could resolve this issue.